# Xamarin.Android - Add item in Spinner Loop

Tags: c#, mysql, for-loop, xamarin.android, spinner

I am new to Xamarin and I'm trying to figure it out. I want to add a few dates from MySql db to a spinner, but I need to use a loop. The loop is there to get all the dates and show them in the spinner, but my code doesn't work. This is my code so far.

```
private static string Email = "";
        private static string SC = "";
public string[] Blank { get; private set; }

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Score);
    
                Spinner cmbSDate = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.cmbSDate);
    
                Email = Intent.GetStringExtra("Email");

                DB SCDB = new DB();
            MySqlCommand SCCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT `Squad Code` from Accounts 
            where Email = @Email", SCDB.getConnection());
            SCCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Email;
            SCDB.openConnection();
            var SCResult = SCCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            if (SCResult != null)
            {
                SC = Convert.ToString(SCResult);
            }
    
                ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, DateStrings());
           }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
private string[] DateStrings()
        {
            int rows = 0;
            String[] Dates;

            DB SCDB = new DB();
            DataTable SCTable = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter SCAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            MySqlCommand SCCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from `ComboBox` WHERE `Squad Code` = @SC", SCDB.getConnection());
            SCCommand.Parameters.Add("@SC", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SC;
            SCAdapter.SelectCommand = SCCommand;
            SCAdapter.Fill(SCTable);
            SCDB.openConnection();
            if (SCTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                rows = SCTable.Rows.Count;
            }

            for (int N = 1; N <= rows; N++)
            {
                DB DB = new DB();
                DataTable Table = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT `Date` from `ComboBox` WHERE `Squad Code` = @SC AND `Row` = @R", DB.getConnection());
                Command.Parameters.Add("@SC", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SC;
                Command.Parameters.Add("@R", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = N;
                DB.openConnection();
                Adapter.SelectCommand = Command;
                Adapter.Fill(Table);
                var Result = Command.ExecuteScalar();
                if (Result != null)
                {
                    Dates = (string[])Result;
                    return Dates;
                }
            }
            Dates = (string[])Blank;
            return Dates;
        }
```

I need help please.

Comment: Is there any log about this problem?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.' @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: Which line of code reported this error?If it is convinient for you, could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?